# Implementation of dark mode with variables in React/Sass project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I am working on a Sass project and I am pretty new to it.

I have a `_variables.scss` file which contains the variables for UI. I want to change the values of those variables **dynamically** (*not creating new ones*), with the use of React. How can I do so?

Expected Outcome is something like:
In scss file,
Check if dark mode is active or not and define a set of variables.

In js file,
Change the state of light and dark mode programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Create SCSS folder and put your all the application .scss files inside there.

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    colorBackground: white,
    colorBackgroundBody: #f2f4f7,
    colorHeaderDataPicker:#6db0ff,
    colorText: #646777,
    colorTextAdditional: #646777,
    logoImg: url(../../shared/img/logo/oiclogo.png),
    colorHover: #fafbfe,
    colorFolderHover: #f0eeee,
    colorBorder: #eff1f5,
    colorIcon: #dddddd,
    imgInvert: invert(0%),
    colorFieldsBorder: #f2f4f7,
    colorBubble: rgba(242, 244, 247, 0.65),
    colorBubbleActive: rgba(234, 238, 255, 0.6),
    colorScrollbar: #B4BFD0,
    colorFitness: #646777,
    colorEmoji: #232329,
  ),
  dark: (
    colorBackground: #232329,
    colorBackgroundBody: #2a2a31,
    colorHeaderDataPicker:#063263,
    colorText: #dddddd,
    colorTextAdditional: #999999,
    logoImg: url(../../shared/img/logo/oiclogo.png),
    colorHover: #38373f,
    colorFolderHover: #ffffff1A,
    colorBorder: #333246,
    colorIcon: #605f7b,
    imgInvert: invert(100%),
    colorFieldsBorder: #33333a,
    colorBubble: rgba(68, 79, 97, 0.65),
    colorBubbleActive: rgba(92, 104, 156, 0.6),
    colorScrollbar: #606071,
    colorFitness: #ffffff,
    colorEmoji: #ffffff,
  )
);
```

Use this structure in **_variables.scss** file
and change the property accordingly

Comment: Any pointers or tutorials on how to change scss properties through react?

Comment: https://youtu.be/9vMyoT7G7uA might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$dark: #333
$white: #fff

@if $theme == 'dark' {
  color: $dark;
}

@if $theme == 'light' {
  color: $light;
}
```

This approach [is described](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#flow-control-scope) at sass lang website. You can set `$theme` variable as regular variable as described in example in documentation.

If you are using webpack as a module bundler and sass-loader package as sass builder, you can set `$theme` variable in the webpack config:

```
{
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    additionalData: "$theme: 'dark';",
  },
}
```

Also I would highly reccomend you to read about [`prefered-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media querie if you will have only light and dark themes. It allows to takes into consideration users operation system defaults.

Comment: Hi. It looks like preferred-color-scheme is soon going to be deprecated. Mozilla states "Deprecated. Not for use in new websites." at the end. I get that the variables can be changed from the webpack config, but what I want is a dynamic approach. The themes should change on press of a button. Is it not possible?

Comment: I think this message about its deprecation is appearing there by accident. There is neither word about it on W3C deprecated media queries page or W3C prefered color sceme rule. Check it: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/#mf-deprecated https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-adjust-1/#preferred